# How to initialize a const char* and/or const std::string in C++ with a sequence of UTF-8 character?

Tags: c++, utf-8

How to initialize a const char* and/or const std::string in C++ with a sequence of UTF-8 characters?

I'm using a regular expression API that accepts UTF8 string as const char*. The initialization code should be platform independent.

Comment: Available options depend on which compiler you are using.

Comment: Easily. `const char* c = "ěščř";`. Just save the file in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: The options also depend on how readable the UTF-8 string should be in the source code.

Comment: An arbitrary string provided at runtime, or a string that's known at compile time? If the former, how is it provided? As a special case if it's the latter, and if your string contains only ascii (7bit) characters, then UTF-8 is the same as ascii for those characters, so just use a string literal. `const char *utf8_string = "hello, world";`. Assuming your platform uses ascii as its basic encoding, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work with any compiler:

```
const char* twochars = "\xe6\x97\xa5\xd1\x88";
```

Answer (score 2):

Compiler - independent answer is also:
Save the file in UTF-8 **without BOM** signature encoding.

```
const char* c = "ěščř"; //Just save the file in UTF-8 without BOM signature.
```

(See the comment of question.) 

Btw, Windows console must bee set to UTF8. For many details see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19080062/2826628) into [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6072342/2826628).

Comment: This should be the recommended practice nowadays. Make it clear that all your source code is UTF-8 with no BOM, make no exceptions, always use UTF-8 for all your files, and then, initialise constant strings as the C/C++ standard way supports.