# C++ string encoding UTF8 / unicode

Tags: c++

I am trying to be able to send character "Т" (not a normal capital t, unicode decimal value 1058) from C++ to VB

However, with this method below Message is returned to VB and it appears as "Ð¢", which is the above character encoded in ANSI.

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER > 1310
# define utf8(str)  ConvertToUTF8(L##str)
const char * ConvertToUTF8(const wchar_t * pStr) {
    static char szBuf[1024];
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pStr, -1, szBuf, sizeof(szBuf), NULL, NULL);
    return szBuf;
}
#else
# define utf8(str)  str
#endif


BSTR _stdcall chatTest()
{
    BSTR Message;
    CString temp("temp test");
    temp+=utf8("\u0422");
    int len = temp.GetLength();
    Message = SysAllocStringByteLen ((LPCTSTR)temp, len+1 );
    return Message;
}
```

If I just do temp+=("\u0422"); without the utf8 function.  It sends the data as "?" and its actually a question mark (sometimes unicode characters show up as question marks in VB, but still have the correct unicode decimal value.. this is not the case here... it changes it to a question mark.

In VB if I output the String variable  that has data from Message when it is "Ð¢" to a text file it appears as the "Т".

So as far as I can tell its in UTF8 in C++, then somehow gets converted to ANSI in VB (or before its sent?), and then when outputted to a file its changed back to UTF8?

I just need to keep the "Т" intact when sending from C++ to VB.  I know VB strings can hold that character because from another source within VB I am able to store it (it appears as a "?", but has the proper unicode decimal value).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why use such a beautiful language like c++ and then ruin it by using VB? :P

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/a/6072627/13760 for the details of how C++11 solves this problem for you :)

Comment: Mr Universe, because I suck :)

Comment: Which function do you use to print?  Are you printing to a console or what else?

Comment: @Emilio I tried basically everything (I think).  In C++ I tried MessageBox, printf, cout, ofstream to print to file.

In MessageBox the "Т" character shows up as "Ð¢" (I googled this, and I dont think MessageBox can show some unicode characters)
In printf, and cout it shows up as "?" iirc
when outputted to file with ofstream it shows up properly as "Ð¢"

In VB, I just use Print #, and it shows up in the file as "Т", but during runtime in VB it shows up as "Ð¢"

Comment: Similar to MessageBox I dont think VB can show some unicode characters by default, but when its done "properly" I think it shows up as a "?" with the correct unicode code.

Comment: Here is the ghetto solution I came up with that works for what I need.
I made another function in C++ that I send a string to from VB and it just sends it back.  Somehow that converts all the unicode characters to "?" and then in C++ for the other string I use MultiByteToWideChar and it turns the same characters into "?" (not sure why).. but now the data from both Strings match and that solves my problem

Answer (score 1):

A BSTR is not UTF-8, it's UTF-16 which is what you get with the `L""` prefix.  Take out the UTF-8 conversion and use CStringW. And use `LPCWSTR` instead of `LPCTSTR`.

Comment: When I use LPCWSTR instead of LPCTSTR. I get error

'SysAllocStringByteLen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPCWSTR' to 'LPCSTR'

Comment: @user1088794 try using `SysAllocStringLen` instead.

Comment: Doesn't work.  When it sends to VB it still converts the character to a "?".  And also has gaps between all the characters.